# Talking to Redis (Redis To Go) from an IOS 5 app

Tags: ios5, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a web-based program that uses the Pub/Sub interface to Redis To Go to publish messages, that are then subscribed to by a web-based service I use. The web-based service subscribes to these messages and speaks them over the phone.

Now I would like to replace this web-based client part with a client running on my iPhone. Using IOS 5, I would like to publish the messages to Redis.

Is this possible? I've Googled around and am not turning up much.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/lp/ObjCHiredis it is a wrapper around hiredis but it has not been updated in a while. Hiredis itself https://github.com/antirez/hiredis is the official C client so you can either work with the first or build on top of hiredis yourself.

Comment: I'm a novice Objective-C programmer, and I'm nervous, since this doesn't seem to be a very well-trodden path. It makes me suspect it might not be a good idea.  My data flow goes like this. My IOS app get's user's long and lat, and sends a request to my other app on Google App engine. Google App Engine returns JSON to my IOS app, and now I want to send it to Redis. I wish Google App Engine could just send it to Redis directly, but I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: I am not familiar with Google App Engine but I would not be using iOS app in this way. I think you need to be looking at how to get App Engine to talk to Redis that is a better approach I think

Comment: With GAE, you can install pure Python modules, including this one: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py (the hiredis parser being optional).

Comment: Thanks. That would be great if that redis-py module works for me. I'll report back to this thread, if it does.

Comment: Here's my report. Sockets aren't supported on GAE, and redis-py uses sockets, ergo redis-py won't run on Google App Engine. http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#libraries